# Excel Graph API "argument is invalid" if PATCH a range where sheet name has spaces

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The following PATCH fails with and without URL encoding the spaces:

```
./v1.0/me/drive/items/<workbookId>}/workbook/worksheets('My%20Sheet')/range(address='My%20Sheet!A2:B3')
```

"The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."

Works fine for sheets without spaces.

Is there a workaround for this other than not using spaces for sheet names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can ignore the sheet name since we have provided the sheet name under the worksheets collection. Here is an sample works well for me:

```
PATCH: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01G4KMWSA62PBFZW7MZBB2SXJKMBHLAREG/workbook/worksheets('Sheet%202')/range(address='A1:B2')
```